# How do I ensure that my matrix is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I require a positive definite matrix, $M$, with dimensions $2n\times2n$ of the form
\begin{equation}
M=\begin{pmatrix}
\Sigma&P'\\
P&\Sigma
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $\Sigma$ is a $n\times{}n$ positive definite matrix. What are the constraints on $P$ that ensure that $M$ is positive definite?

Comment: Is $P^{\prime}$ supposed to be the transpose of $P$?

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: Using Schur complements we obtain the constraint: $\Sigma \ge P'\Sigma^{-1}P$ which is required for ensuring $M \ge 0$.